# WordPress storing all post titles of CPT in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a CPT 'jobs' and would like to store all post titles in an array.

This is what I've tried but for some reason I get `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$myarray = array();

$jobs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'jobs') ); 
foreach ($jobs as $job):
    $myarray = $job->post_title; 
endforeach; 

echo $myarray;
```

I've dumped the $jobs wp_query and I can see the post_titles there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `get_posts`. It only returns the `$posts` property from the query object. Also, you are missing the array syntax (*`[]`*) after `$myarray`. As it stands, `$myarray` will only hold the current post title of the post being looped through. As a final note, you cannot echo an array, you can only echo strings

```
$myarray = array();

$jobs = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'jobs') ); 
foreach ($jobs as $job):
    $myarray[] = $job->post_title; 
endforeach; 

var_dump( $myarray );
```

Comment: Cool it works! My actual goal is to get this array in my jQuery script in the same file. Is this even possible? To use this array in my jQuery?

Comment: Totally possible, look at [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Don't let the name fool you, it is also used to pass PHP variables to JS. If you do come right, please feel free to start a new question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

```
<?php
$myarray = array();

$jobs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','orderby=title&order=DESC') ); 
global $post;

if($jobs->have_posts()){
    while ($jobs->have_posts()):$jobs->the_post();
        $myarray[] = $post->post_title;
    endwhile;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarray);
?>
```